# Converting inline ASM to intrinsic for x64 igraph

Tags: c++, c, assembly, visual-studio-2012, intrinsics

I'm compiling from source the python extension IGRAPH for x64 instead of x86 which is available in the distro.  I have gotten it all sorted out in VS 2012 and it compiles when I comment out as follows in src/math.c

```
#ifndef HAVE_LOGBL
long double igraph_logbl(long double x) {
long double res;
/**#if defined(_MSC_VER)
  __asm { fld [x] }
  __asm { fxtract }
  __asm { fstp st }
  __asm { fistp [res] }
 #else
 __asm__ ("fxtract\n\t"
 "fstp  %%st" : "=t" (res) : "0" (x));
 #endif*/
    return res;
 }
#endif
```

The problem is I don't know asm well and I don't know it well enough to know if there are issues going from x86 to x64.  This is a short snippet of 4 assembly intsructions that have to be converted to x64 intrinsics, from what I can see.

Any pointers?  Is going intrinsic the right way?  Or should it be subroutine or pure C?

Edit: Link for igraph extension if anyone wanted to see http://igraph.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: There is no intrinsic for `fxtract`, so that plan fails immediately. If you're willing to switch you non-long doubles, you can extract the exponent easily with SSE2 intrinsics (that'll be much quicker than `fxtract`, by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In x64 floating point will generally be performed using the SSE2 instructions as these are generally a lot faster.  Your only problem here is that there is no equivalent to the fxtract op in SSE (Which generally means the FPU version will be implemented as a compound instruction and hence very slow).  So implementing as a C function will likely be just as fast on x64.

I'm finding the function a bit hard to read however as from what I can tell it is calling fxtract and then storing an integer value to the address pointed to by a long double.  This means the long double is going to have a 'partially' undefined value in it.  As best I can tell the above code assembly shouldn't work ... but its been a VERY long time since I wrote any x87 code so I'm probably just rusty.

Anyway the function, appears to be an implementation of [logb](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/logb.3.html) which you won't find implemented in MSVC.  It can, however, be implemented as follows using the frexp function:

```
long double igraph_logbl(long double x) 
{
    int exp = 0;
    frexpl( x, &exp );
    return (long double)exp;
 }
```

Comment: Interesting.  according to the web, frexp is only in double version in plain C and you'd have to go to cpp to get long double.  igraph is technically all C, I think.

Comment: @WildaBeast: Where do you get that info from?  One big issue is that long double no longer really exist with SSE2 (Not that it really exist at all ... i mean .. what size is a long double?) ... it all gets casted to double anyway (at least with VS2012).